# Regular Expression: Extract the lines

Tags: regex

I try to extract the name1 (first-row), name2 (second-row), name3 (third-row) and the street-name (last-row) with regex:

```
Company Inc.
JohnDoe
Foobar
Industrieterrein 13
```

The very last row is the street name and this part is already working (the text is stored in the variable "S2").

```
REGEXREPLACE(S2, "(.*\n)+(?!(.*\n))", "")
```

This expression will return me the very last line. I am also able the extract the first row:

```
REGEXREPLACE(S2, "(\n.*)", "")
```

My problem is, that I do not know how to extract the second and third row....

Also how do I test if the text contains one, two, three or more rows?

**Update**:

The regex is used in the context of Scribe (a ETL tool). The problem is I can not execute sourcecode, I only have the following functions:

- `REGEXMATCH(input, pattern)`
- `REGEXREPLACE(input, pattern, replacement)`

Comment: What programming language are you using?  Otherwise how are we to know how to test how many rows there are?

Comment: No need for regex, at least not for advanced pattern matching - just _split_ the text on newline (with whatever split implementation your language provides).

Comment: Likely a better answer than my regex solution @CBroe

Comment: The regex is used in the context of Scribe (a ETL tool). The problem is I can not execute sourcecode, I only have the following functions:"REGEXMATCH( input, pattern )" and "REGEXREPLACE( input, pattern, replacement )"

Comment: Does the language allow lookaheads?

Comment: Yes, I assume so. I though the expression "(.*\n)+(?!(.*\n))" is using lookaheads and this expression is working.

Comment: `.*?\n` will match a line, because it's not greedy.  I would think `.*\n` would match everything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the regex language provides support for lookaheads you may count rows backwards and thus get (assuming `.` does not match newline)

```
(.*)$                   # matching the last line
(.*)(?=(\n.*){1}$)      # matching the second last line (excl. newline)
(.*)(?=(\n.*){2}$)      # matching the third last line (excl. newline)
```

Comment: Hi, I can only use the function "REGEXREPLACE( input, pattern, replacement )". Question is: How to i use your expressions in this context? So what I need is "match all, except second line and repalce with an empty string"?

Comment: @thuld Do I understand correctly, that you want to keep only the second line? Then why not use `REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(input,"^.*\n",""),"\n(\n|.)*","")` - inner replace to remove first line and outer replace to remove anything after the first.

Comment: yes, one part of the requirement is the extract of the second line. I will test your recommendation tomorrow, thanks for the help! Last question: Do you agree that this Statement will Keep the third line? REGEXREPLACE( REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(input,"^.*\n",""),"^.*\n",""),"\n(\n|.)*","" )

Answer (score 2):

just use this regex:

```
(.+)+
```

explain:

> ***`.`***
>   Wildcard: Matches any single character except `\n`.
>
> ***`+`***
>   Matches the previous element one or more times.

Answer (score 1):

As for a regular expression that will match each of four rows, how about this:

```
(.*?)\n(.*?)\n(.*?)\n(.*)
```

The parentheses will match, and the \n will match a new line.  Note: you may have to use `\r\n` instead of just `\n` depending; try both.

Comment: Ok, so with this expression i could test if the text contains 1, 2, 3,... rows. But how to I replace all except the second row?

Comment: guessing from your answer, something like `REGEXREPLACE(S2, "(.*?)\n(.*?)\n(.*?)\n(.*)", "replaced\n\2\nreplaced\nreplaced")`.  The 2 is a back reference. It should stand for the 2nd parentheses in the regex.  But depending on the programming language, it might be a different number, or it might be `$2`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

`((.*?)\n){3}`